# Getting error from Arcpy Tabulate_area

Tags: arcpy, error-999999

I am trying to get the area of land use in each pixel of the fishnet file. I used the following script:

`arcpy.gp.TabulateArea_sa("fishnet_layer","FID","lulc.tif","Value","lulc_tab","1.1E-3")`

Here `fishnet_layer` is the layer of fishnet shapefile which consists of 2000 pixels and `lulc.tif` is the land use image.

The above script gives the error:

`ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
("esriDataSourcesRaster.GdalRasterDataset") Failed to open raster dataset
ERROR 010419: Unable to build the attribute table of raster as required by the operation.
Failed to execute (TabulateArea).`

Comment: Are you using an integer raster?  If not, I think the error message is pointing to your problem.